# USB install Ubuntu 22.04 display resolution fixed to 860x640, not able to show full installation page so not able to continue

Tags: display, display-resolution

I'm trying to USB install Ubuntu 22.04 on an Intel NUC Extreme 13, however the resolution is fixed to 860x640 and cannot be changed. As a result I'm not able to show the full installation page, because the Continue button is on the bottom of the page, so is not displayed.

[image: Not able to see continue button]

I guess this is due to the display driver. As the following figure shows, the graphics card is llvmpipe.

[image: The hardware of my NUC]

Comment: The installer you appear to be using requires a larger screen resolution that you appear to have available; did you try *safe graphics*?  Did you try a different kernel stack (eg. 22.04.2 media will use the 5.19 kernel where as 22.04.1 used 5.15).  I take it from your pictures you're trying to install Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop (*you didn't specify Server/Desktop or product details*).

Comment: Thanks @guiverc, I tried 22.04.2 and it works.

Comment: Just FYI:  but *drivers* are actually kernel modules.. thus using a newer/later kernel gave you newer/later kernel modules (aka. newer/later *drivers*). That applies to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop media with .2 or above  (Server will still use the GA kernel stack & thus remains at 5.15 for all of 22.04)

Answer (score 0):

Tried 22.04.2 and it is good now